# How to have a remote terminal inside Spacemacs, like a PuTTy within Emacs?

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, tramp, ssh

My question is about mimicking PuTTy inside Spacemacs in Windows, not about using Spacemacs via PuTTy.

That is, I am interested in learning whether it is possible to open within Spacemacs a remote terminal such that I could do within Spacemacs what I currently do in PuTTy. I know that one can work on remote files, by using the built-in TRAMP layer and doing something like `C-x Cf`and entering the remote address (e.g. `/ssh:myusername@hostaddress:root/home/myfile.txt`.

However, I never found anything about how to open just the remote terminal from the server being connected to. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've been used

`M-x shell` to open a shell
and, at the shell prompt, `ssh remoteUser@remoteIp`

to check if port 22 is open in remoteIp: `nmap remoteIp`

my apologises: I'm not sure if works on windows box